Tailwind base remove border and padding
I'm currently working on a project using the Calendar component from PrimeReact, and I've encountered an issue where the border and padding seem to be missing. I have a themes.css file in my public folder because I want the website to allow dynamic theme switching. This file is imported in the  section.
However, if I import the theme CSS directly from the PrimeReact node_modules folder instead, the padding and border are correctly displayed.
One thing I've tried is removing Tailwind's base styles from globals.css, and when I do that, the padding and border reappear, but obviously, this breaks the styling for other components. When I inspect the Calendar component, it shows Tailwind's base layer applied first, followed by PrimeReact's styles.
How can I resolve this conflict between Tailwind's base styles and PrimeReact's theme?
globals.css
@layer primereact, tailwind-base, tailwind-utilities;

@layer tailwind-base {
  @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}





Have you tried applying styles in a different orders ? I would try to to adjust the layer order like so (in your global.scss file):
@layer tailwind-base {
  @tailwind base;
}

@layer primereact {
  @import 'path/to/primereact/theme.css';
   or
  @import primeract;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}

I suppose by doing so, primereact should take precedence over tailwind.
